# How to filter xml records by various values (combination filter) in js/.net

Tags: javascript, html, xml, vb.net

I have a xml file with around 1000 records in it and I need to be able to filter the records based on various parameters be it name, price, colour and so on to then produce a result set listing all records that match the specified criteria.
Technologies I have at my disposal are vb.net, javascript and output will be transforming the xml result set to html to pretty up the results for general user consumption and offer the ability to page results for speed of loading.

I've looked at xpath but most examples are quite limiting and only return specific fields rather than full records, I've also looked at json path as I can easily convert between xml and json.

Json Path works with JSON version of the below xml

```
$..Product[?(@.Gender.male == 'true' && @.Brand.isdesigner == 'true')]
```

Which works pretty well but I'm wondering if their is an easier way to make this work and retain the flexibility

Sample of the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <Product>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <ThumbImg>IMG.jpg</ThumbImg>
    <PTID>0</PTID>
    <BID>0</BID>
    <name>Item name</name>
    <type>Type name</type>
    <price>0.00</price>
    <discountprice>0.00</discountprice>
    <Brand>
      <Name>Brand name</Name>
      <isdesigner>true</isdesigner>
      <discount>0</discount>
      <discounttype>percentage</discounttype>
    </Brand>
    <Gender>
      <male>false</male>
      <female>true</female>
    </Gender>
    <shape>Item shape</shape>
    <style>Item style</style>
    <colour>
      <black>false</black>
      <grey>false</grey>
      <white>false</white>
      <brown>false</brown>
      <red>false</red>
      <orange>false</orange>
      <yellow>false</yellow>
      <green>false</green>
      <blue>true</blue>
      <purple>false</purple>
      <pink>false</pink>
      <silver>false</silver>
      <gold>false</gold>
      <transparent>false</transparent>
    </colour>
    <material>2</material>
    <weight>26</weight>
    <sizes>
      <size>52</size>
    </sizes>
  </Product>
</catalog>
```

For example I would want to be able to filter on partial name match, price and brand but could also include filter on any of the properties and return a list of records that match the filter options.

I'm working with flat files to reduce load on the db and allow caching of the full product list user side to make the system fast and responsive without of overheads of a server farm, the data will invalidate itself after a few hours where it will then pull the latest version from the server if required (if the user is still using the website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.Net you can use Linq for Xml like in following example.

```
Dim doc = <catalog>
  <Product>
    <ID>1000</ID>
    <name>Item name</name>
    <price>0.00</price>
    <discountprice>0.00</discountprice>
    <Brand>
      <Name>Brand name</Name>
      <isdesigner>true</isdesigner>
      <discount>0</discount>
      <discounttype>percentage</discounttype>
    </Brand>
  </Product>
</catalog>

Dim query = (From p In doc...<Product> 
             Where p.<Brand>.<Name>.Value.Contains("name") AndAlso 
                   Convert.ToDecimal(p.<price>.Value) < 2.0
             Select p)
```